# How to insert value in extJS displayfield in dom element

Tags: javascript, extjs, extjs6

Here is my displayfield config which is item of form panel..

```
{
    fieldLabel: "Class"
    itemId: "class"
    name: "class"
    readOnly: true
    value: "my Class"
    xtype: "displayfield"
}
```

I have a extJS displayfield which is working fine but in some case even though the value is available, value is not displaying. Even the value is coming in after render method.

```
 afterrender: function(val, eOpts){
        let _this = this,
            view = _this.getView();
            console.log(view.itemId +" "+view.value);
            
           
    }
```

After my deep debug I noticed the value itself is not there in dom. SO I am planning to insert the element in dom afterrender method. Can anybody suggest me how I can insert value in displayfield dom.

my id is like this, but this is not working properly. some time style and label only getting disapper.

```
afterrender: function(val, eOpts){
        let _this = this,
            view = _this.getView();
            console.log(view.itemId +" "+view.value);
             view.el.dom.innerText = view.value;
           
    }
```

Comment: Checkout income data (json?) when displayfield is empty.

Comment: I am getting value in data.

Comment: What kind of data? Can you show incoming json for your form?

Comment: I am using mongo so the json data which I am giving form the field config in question, that only I am getting.

Comment: The error seems to be in a different place. try: `Ext.first('#formItemId').getForm().findField('displayFieldName').setValue(12)`. Here is a fiddle with two possible ways to fill the data into the displayfield

Comment: Fiddle: https://fiddle.sencha.com/#view/editor&fiddle/3910

Answer (score 1):

It's not clear how your field is getting the data.
If I understand you correctly, you should use *displayfield.setValue()* method like this:

[here is working fiddle](https://fiddle.sencha.com/#view/editor&fiddle/38rr)

According to your description it is difficult to understand the reason why displayfield dont display some value. But you can check it for yourself by looking *console.log(IdOfYourDisplayField);*